# Cypress E2E - cy.session and cy.origin not working for two different users

Tags: cypress, e2e-testing

I want to use the same login command for two users. I have used cy.session in the login command. But it throws an error for the second user login. The login command involves cy.origin because the website under test redirects to Microsoft login and redirects back to website after authentication.

Login command:

```
Cypress.Commands.add("login", (user) =>

 {

 cy.sqlServer(select USERID, password from table name where User=${user}).then(function (result) { 

   var userID = result[0]
   var password = result[1] 
   const credentials = { userID, password }

   cy.session([userID, password], () => {
   cy.viewport('macbook-16')
   cy.visit('https://websitename.com/')
   cy.get('.login-btn').click()
   //clicking accept cookie button
   cy.get('#onetrust-accept-btn-handler').should('be.visible').click()

   //clicking microsoft login button
   cy.get('#microsoft-external-auth-button').should('be.visible').click()
   //redirected to microsoft login
   cy.origin('https://login.microsoftonline.com/', { args: credentials }, ({ userID, password }) => {

   //entering username

   //clicking next

   //entering password

    //clicking 'login' button

    cy.wait(1000)      })    })  })})
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CH68q.png)